# Find site of apache from linux process table

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, ps

I am using Ubuntu server and when I run `ps aux` I get the following process table http://pastebin.com/NJsASBek as we can see apache proceess are shown like this:

> www-data 26487 0.0 0.9 245476 14920 ? Sl 17:32 0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2
>   -k start

Where 2687 is the PID. 
How can I know wich of my enabled sites belong that process?

This is how my apache sites are defined http://pastebin.com/mcew79sH of course I am willing to edit my apache sites if needed.

Comment: As Kyle notes, the apache processes can be serving any virtual host defined your configuration.  What are you actually trying to figure out?

Comment: Basically I want to know which sites (lets say the ServerName) are consuming more memory, and which consume less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default MPM is `prefork`, which creates (as you've seen) a pre-forked Apache process that is waiting for a connection to serve a request.  It does not fire off different processes for different `VirtualHost` declarations, so any given process *could* serve any of your sites.

As processes are restarted after a configurable number of requests have been served (or an idle timer passes, and the forks are cleaned up), it's possible that any given process has served pages from *multiple* `VirtualHosts`.

Comment: So... how can I know which sites are consuming more memory at a specific moment?

Comment: Maybe you should change the title/question or start a new one for that since the current question has been answered.

Comment: I have created a new one http://serverfault.com/questions/376054/how-may-i-know-the-ammount-of-memory-used-by-each-one-of-my-apache-sites thanks

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that they are using mod_wsgi and specifically mod_wsgi daemon mode with the WSGI application delegated to that separate set of processes. More specific answer which deals with that in duplicate question.

Comment: +1'd on your post.  I'm not familiar with WSGI, clearly :-)